# Is it possible to implement RC-5 not using interrupts?

Tags: microcontroller, c, atmega, timer, remote-control

The problem with my `atmega8` is that I don't have the external interrupts `INT0` or `INT1` available. There are some nice libraries, e.g. [this one](https://github.com/pinkeen/avr-rc5), that rely on the interrupts, however, I would like to achieve that by not using them.

Is it a feasible plan?

Comment: @Colin__s well, currently I am trying to find a workaround for counting microseconds precisely in order to check the phase shifts.

Comment: It might help to clarify what rc5 is.  In my sad world, RC5 is a symmetric-key block cipher which therefore shouldn't need any interrupts.

Comment: @PaulUszak It should be RC-5, a protocol for infrared communication. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC-5

Comment: @Colin__s sure. I thought that is why the tags are there, isn't it? :)

Comment: RC5 (what OP wrote) is a block cipher. RC-5 is a remote control communication protocol.

Comment: "I don't have the external interrupts INT0 or INT1 available" - what _do_ you have available? The analog comparator can generate an interrupt.

Comment: Why don't you have `INT0` or `INT1`?

Answer (score 2):

Well you could do it by polling the input regularly in your program however this would be very inefficient compared to using interrupts. The Atmega8 does have external interrupts available.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is quite feasible. An [RC-5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC-5#Protocol_Details) code word takes ~25ms to transmit and is repeated every 114ms. So you could poll the input until a complete code word is received, then you have 89ms to do other stuff before going back to polling. If you miss a word or two it won't matter because the same command is retransmitted for the whole time that the button is pressed on the remote.

The example code in the library you linked to actually polls. All you have to do is change the interrupt handler to a normal function, and wait for the pin to change state before calling it. If you include a timeout in the wait then it can be non-blocking.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you could poll one of the ADC pins, but your chip has other interrupts you could put to use. The Atmega8 [interrupt vector table](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts.html) includes `ADC_vect`, `ANA_COMP_vect`, `EE_RDY_vect`, `INT0_vect`, `INT1_vect`, `SPI_STC_vect`, `SPM_RDY_vect`, `TIMER0_OVF_vect`, `TIMER1_CAPT_vect`, `TIMER1_COMPA_vect`, `TIMER1_COMPB_vect`, `TIMER1_OVF_vect`, `TIMER2_COMP_vect`, `TIMER2_OVF_vect`, `TWI_vect`, `USART_RXC_vect`, `USART_TXC_vect`, and `USART_UDRE_vect`. You mentioned that the external interrupt pins have been purposed for something else, and the linked library uses Timer 1.

You could use the analog-to-digital comparator interrupt:

> Using mega8515 as an example:
>
> `ACSR = 0x0B; // Configured the Analog Comparator
>      sei();   // Enable ACIE and set interrupt to
>               // trigger whenever AC0 go high. That
>               // is both ACIS1 and ACIS0 are set to 1.`
>
> Use it like this:
>
> `while(!(PINA & 0x10))
>   {
>       // Turn/keep everything off
>       // Can make this non-blocking by calling it from another timer ISR
>   }
>   // Do your thing`

by [Atmel (AVR Analog Comparator Interrupt Feature)](http://www.avr-tutorials.com/comparator/utilizing-avr-analog-comparator-interrupt-feature)

> Using mega16 as an example:
>
> Setup, init, etc:
>
> `DDRA&=~(1<<AINpin);  //as input
>   PORTA&=~(1<<AINpin);  //no Pull-up
>   ACSR|=
>       (0<<ACD)|   //Comparator ON
>       (1<<ACBG)|  //Connect 1.23V reference to AIN0
>       (1<<ACIE)|  //Comparator Interrupt enable
>       (0<<ACIC)|  //input capture disabled
>       (0<<ACIS1)| //set interrupt on output toggle
>       (0<<ACIS0);
>   sei();           //enable global interrupts`
>
> ISR handler:
>
> `ISR(ANA_COMP_vect) {
>   if bit_is_clear(ACSR, ACO)
>       // Do your thing
>   }`

from [AVR Comparator C programming example](http://winavr.scienceprog.com/avr-gcc-tutorial/avr-comparator-c-programming-example.html)

You can configure a timer as an external interrupt by setting it to run off of an external clock and to overflow after a single clock tick, and using the signal you're looking for as the external clock. I don't have a reference, but here's a quick run-down:

1. Setup Timer 2 to use external clock. This pin will be your [sorry excuse for an] external interrupt pin.
2. Setup in one of the two Clear Timer on Compare (CTC) modes with the compare value set to 1. (Maybe 2? Does it start at 1 or 0? Anyway, you'll figure it out.)
3. Write `ISR (TIMER2_COMPA_vect)` (`...COMPB...`) to do your thing.

Alternative to CTC mode is to use the `TIMER2_CAPT_vect`, which triggers on every pulse. (Actually, that sounds better than the CTC option.)

A decent timer example is here: [QEEWiki - My Books‎ > ‎AVR GUIDE‎ > ‎ Timers on the ATmega8](https://sites.google.com/site/qeewiki/books/avr-guide/timer-on-the-atmega8)

You may be able to re-purpose one of the hardware communication interrupts to act like an external interrupt. For example, make your signal appear to be valid  115200bps USART transmission by putting a circuit that pulls the pin `LOW` for at least 1/115200 seconds (8.7us) (e.g. RC and transistor) between the RC-5 output and `RXD` (`PD0`), which will fire off a `USART_RXC_vect` after about 9/115200 seconds (78us).

If you every move away from the old Atmega8 you could use a pin change interrupts:

> Using a mega48/88/168 as an example:
>
> Set the bits of the appropriate `PCMSKx` register high to enable pin
>   change detection on that pin. For `PD2` (`PCINT18`) that would be:
>
> `PCMSK2 |= (1<<PCINT18);`
>
> Then enable the interrupt for the corresponding
>   vector and of course the global interrupt flag:
>
> `PCICR |= (1<<PCIE2);
>   sei();`
>
> Then provide the ISR for that vector that does what you need.
>   For avr-gcc this would look like this:
>
> `ISR(PCINT2_vect)
>   {
>       // Your code here
>   }`
>
> For one pin (or more generally, one pin per `PCINT` vector), that is all you really need. If you have more that one
>   pin per vector enabled, then you have to have code
>   in the ISR that determines which of the pins caused the change. This
>   can be done by keeping a variable that stores the value of the
>   register the last time the ISR was run and comparing to the current
>   value. There can be problems with timing issues, however, since by the
>   time you get to the ISR, another pin may have changed (or even worse,
>   the one that did change changed back). These can be difficult to deal
>   with, but how serious a problem it is depends on the characteristics
>   of your application.

[by Koichi on AVRFreaks](http://www.avrfreaks.net/comment/524776#comment-524776)

Answer (score -4):

You have pcint, quite a few of them.

Timer inputs can be reconfigured as external interruots as well.

Comment: No PCINTx on Atmega8, only the newer ones.